# android:change indicator icon and size of expandablelistview used for navigation

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am making an app in which i have to use given images for expandable list view .Actully i am talking of indicator icon and its size which navigate the path.Can anyone tell me how to change that image .Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector" />
```

... where the `setting_selector` is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_arrow" 
         android:state_empty="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_arrow" 
         android:state_expanded="true" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I tried with a selector like yours but it does not work - nothing appears. I had to remove: android:state_empty="true", and move that line below the other line. Using ICS.

Comment: Perfect. Bit misleading on the state though. state_empty does not mean only empty, it also just means closed.

Comment: I also tried your selector and did not have it work.  I changed state_empty=true to state_expanded=false and it did work.    [The google docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) do not describe state_empty as having anything to do with a "closed" state.  I submitted an edit to this answer to reflect this.

Comment: I think there is an error with this code. `<item android:drawable="@drawable/up_arrow" 
         android:state_empty="true" /> should be android:state_expanded=false`

Comment: (happened to me) If down_arrow/up_arrow is image (not xml i.e. shape/layer-list) Don't forget to scale the image (i.e.use layer-list, set item width & height). otherwise, nothing will show.

Comment: I had to change arrow down to expanded false and arrow up to expanded true. `android:state_empty` wasn't working for me

Answer (score 16):

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector"
   />
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_arrow" android:state_expanded="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_arrow" android:state_expanded="false"/>
</selector>
```

He forgot to put

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/down_arrow" android:state_expanded="false"/>
```

in it.
For me, `android:state_empty` not working.

Answer (score 7):

this is efficient way to set group indicator

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_empty="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="-30dp"
            android:top="120dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/panier_plus">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<item android:state_expanded="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="-30dp"
            android:top="120dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/panier_minus"
             >
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the expand/collapsed group icon then

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings_selector);
//position it in the group layout by setting the bounds
//params are left and right bounds
myExpandableList.setIndicatorBounds(345,375);

myExpandableList.setGroupIndicator(d);
```

I'm not too sure about the size of the indicator, setting the indicator bounds can affect the width of the indicator but not the height.

You could remove the indicator by setting the drawable to null, then inflate a custom layout with an image view in it in getGroupView() in the ExpandableAdapter.

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,     ViewGroup parent) {
    View convertView = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customLayout, null);

    return convertView;
}
```

Although this method would require some extra work to get the indicator to change when the group is expanded, such as a listener to tell whether or not a particular group is expanded and change the image accordingly.

Comment: triggs , i want to change size of indicator image .Can you help me in this

Comment: not too sure about the size, you could always use a custom view for the groups. In your ExpandableAdapter, in the getGroupView method return a custom view there. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: but i am still unable to set size of indicator

Comment: A custom view wouldn't use the built in indicator, you would create your own, that way you have more control over the UI elements. You can put an ImageView in the custom layout and specify its size there. I don't know an easy way to change the size, perhaps some one else has a better idea than a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, check my app

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/select_next"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
```

Use follow below like this....

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
             android:state_empty="true" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_remove_black_24dp"
             android:state_expanded="false" />
    </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_up_arrow" android:state_expanded="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_down_arrow" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```