# Change arrow icon background color to blue in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, expandablelistview, imageicon

I have to develop one ExpandableListView. Here i wish to set the arrow icon background color to blue. The default arrow `background color` is gray. But i need the arrow `background color` to be blue in my app. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible for you to edit the Default Drawable provided to the Group Indicator. The only option left is to create a Drawable by yourslf and add it as the background to the Group Indicator like [explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310768/603744)

Comment: hi do you know expandablelistview within another expandablelistview.if you know means tell me please.

Comment: well you have to search for multi level expandable listview. There are certainely examples based on it.

Answer (score 1):

this is efficient way to set group indicator

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_empty="true" >
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="3dp"
            android:top="20dp"
            android:bottom="20dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_down">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<item
    android:state_expanded="false" >
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="3dp"
            android:top="20dp"
            android:bottom="20dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_up">
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Comment: your solution does not help change the color. Only change icon. if you change the drawable to blue that may help. giving color codes to icon will not work

Answer (score 0):

Questions about color went unanswered. Solution would be to alter color in the xml of your vector image.

Open up your vector image and simply change fill color. Or alter bitmap.
android:fillColor