# Change icon of expandable list view

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I would like to change the expanded and default icon of my Expandable List View.
I did some research how to do this and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293738/androidchange-indicator-icon-and-size-of-expandablelistview-used-for-navigation).

I think I did it just as it is described there.
I have 2 icons, the first is called defaulticon.png and the second one expandedicon.png. Bother are located in the drawable folder (not in drawable-hdpi).
My list view declaration looks like this:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/groupindicator">
    </ExpandableListView>
```

The groupindicator is an xml file also located in the drawable folder and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaulticon" android:state_empty="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/expandedicon" android:state_expanded="true"/>
</selector>
```

However the icons do not change. The default icon from the list view disappears and instead there is no icon.
Are there any restrictions with the resources (how big the resources can me (both are 160x160), where they have to be located,...).
I am testing the app on my S3 running Android 4.1.2.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your icon size to 32 X 32, put your icon in `drawable-mdpi` and then try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/expandedicon" android:state_expanded="true"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaulticon"/>
    </selector>
```

Comment: I used the icon create wizard in eclipse for the up/down arrows and they worked great (on lollipop 5.1.1).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, resize your image to 24*24 and then copy it to the `drawable-mdpi` folder in Android. After that, copy and paste this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc"android:state_empty="true"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/downarrow" ></item>
</selector>
```